# Add javascript after a form or at the end of the page

Tags: joomla-2.5, javascript

I have a javascript code and it's necessary load my code after my form or in end of my page.
When I use this code load before my form in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /// my code
</script>
```

How can load javascript after my form? or at the end of the page?
thank you

Comment: It will be better if you mention what form you use and even more information about your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put your Javascript after the form, where ever it's being rendered from:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    // rest of form code
</form>
<script>
    // you Javascript code
</script>
```

If you don't have the JS and form in the same file, then put them in the same file.

Comment: i do it and add code after form but it's load befor my form

Comment: Is this part of a Joomla module, component, plugin or a separate PHP script?

Comment: it's joomla component i want add custom js in listbingo component

Comment: Ahh so the form is being rendered. I can have a look at the component later on if it's a free extension and get back to you

Comment: i want add javascript to this file: administrator/components/com_listbingo/views/ad/tmpl/form.php

Comment: it's only load javascript in head tag i want load in body tag